# attaching handlers to virtual controls in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Here is what i'm trying to accomplish....

I need to be able to register elements that aren't part of the DOM when they are created.

here is the syntax i'm trying to synthesize

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#virtualControl').registerControl(function(){ alert('do something'); });

   // simulate adding the control to the dom
   $('#virtualControls').append($("<a id='virtualControl'>Virtual</a>"));

   $(document).trigger('render'); // at this point it should call the fn that was passed in to the 'register control' function

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to what the [`.livequery()` plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery) does, you can use it like this:

```
$("selector").livequery(function() {
  //this runs when an element found, or added later
});
```

The function you pass runs for every element added later, which seems to be what you're after.